# Regular expression to get numbers from the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String like the following

```
 minmaxSize2-8
 minmaxSize12-20
```

How to get the range from the above strings.I need to get 2-8 and 12-20.
Please suggest the regular expressions in javascript

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
var myString = "minmaxSize12-20";
var myRegexp = /(\d+)-(\d+)/g; // Numbers dash Numbers
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  // 12
alert(match[2]);  // 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var str = 'minmaxSize12-20';
var range = str.replace(/^.*?Size/i, ''); // returns 12-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
"minmaxSize12-20".match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/)
```

or even

```
/(\d+)-(\d+)/.exec("minmaxSize12-20");
```